# Convert UTF16 byte array to normal string

Tags: c#, qt

I'm using encryption/decryption from tiny aes [link](https://intmaker.com/2015/text-encryption-in-qtc-with-tiny-aes-128bit/)

I try to convert that code into C# version ... and what i got is encryption, but I'm unable to 'decrypt' text.

Anyway here is a code for it:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test_raw = "TestText";
            string password = "pA5w0rd";

            string test_enc = encodeText(test_raw, password);
            string test_dec = decodeText(test_enc, password);

            int i = 0;
        }

        // Static IV
        static byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0xf0, 0xe1, 0xd2, 0xc3, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0x96, 0x87, 0x78, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x4b, 0x3c, 0x2d, 0x5e, 0xaf };

        static string decodeText(string hexEncodedText, string key)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            int length = hexEncodedText.Length;
            int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(length, 16);

            byte[] encodedText = GetStringToBytes(hexEncodedText);

            Array.Resize(ref encodedText, encryptionLength);

            byte[] plainTextBytes;
            using (var aes = new AesManaged
            {
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
            })
            {
                using (var decrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor(md5Bytes, iv))
                using (var plainTextStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var decrypterStream = new CryptoStream(plainTextStream, decrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(decrypterStream))
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(encodedText);
                    }

                    plainTextBytes = plainTextStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            //Array.Resize(ref plainTextBytes, plainTextBytes.Length + 2);

            string utf8String = String.Empty;
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, plainTextBytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < utf8Bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                // Because char always saves 2 bytes, fill char with 0
                byte[] utf8Container = new byte[2] { utf8Bytes[i], 0 };
                utf8String += BitConverter.ToChar(utf8Container, 0);

            }


            int i_some_val = 0;

            return "";
        }

        // Encrypt text using key(password)
        static string encodeText(string rawText, string key)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            byte[] inputData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rawText);
            int length = inputData.Length + 1;
            int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(length, 16);

            Array.Resize(ref inputData, encryptionLength);

            byte[] cipherText;
            using (var aes = new AesManaged
            {
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
            })
            {
                using (var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(md5Bytes, iv))
                using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(inputData);
                    }

                    cipherText = cipherStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return GetBytesToString(cipherText);
        }

        public static int getAlignedSize(int currSize, int alignment)
        {
            int padding = (alignment - currSize % alignment) % alignment;
            return currSize + padding;
        }

        public static byte[] GetStringToBytes(string value)
        {
            SoapHexBinary shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
            return shb.Value;
        }

        public static string GetBytesToString(byte[] value)
        {
            SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary(value);
            return shb.ToString();
        }
    }


}
```

When i print 'output' is fine as data have \0 char - so is printing correctly - but i need to use that value later on, so my idea was to cut of (junk data) rest of array and just get 'raw value'

Comment: Interesting part of qt version is this append at end:
`int size_1 = encodedText.size();
encodedText.append("\0\0");
int size_2 = encodedText.size();`

Both sizes are same, even if code should add 2 chars extra?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to convert back from UTF16 to UTF8
Then create string from array, and just cut first instance of \0

C# version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        // For testing ...
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static string GetRandomString(int length)
        {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var result = new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
                            .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                            .ToArray());

            return result;
        }

        // 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "pA5w0rd";

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"data.txt"))
            {
                for (int num = 1; num < 2048; num++)
                {
                    string random_s = GetRandomString(num);
                    string test_enc = encodeText(random_s, password);
                    string test_dec = decodeText(test_enc, password);

                    file.WriteLine(random_s);
                    file.WriteLine(test_enc);
                }
            }
        }

        // Static IV
        static byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0xf0, 0xe1, 0xd2, 0xc3, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0x96, 0x87, 0x78, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x4b, 0x3c, 0x2d, 0x5e, 0xaf };

        // Decrypt text using key(password)
        static string decodeText(string hexEncodedText, string key)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            int length = hexEncodedText.Length;
            int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(length, 16);

            byte[] encodedText = GetStringToBytes(hexEncodedText);

            Array.Resize(ref encodedText, encryptionLength);

            byte[] plainTextBytes;
            using (var aes = new AesManaged
            {
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
            })
            {
                using (var decrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor(md5Bytes, iv))
                using (var plainTextStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var decrypterStream = new CryptoStream(plainTextStream, decrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(decrypterStream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(encodedText);
                    }

                    plainTextBytes = plainTextStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            string utf8String = String.Empty;
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, plainTextBytes);

            utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
            int index = utf8String.IndexOf('\0');
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                utf8String = utf8String.Remove(index);
            }

            return utf8String;
        }

        // Encrypt text using key(password)
        static string encodeText(string rawText, string key)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            byte[] inputData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rawText + "\0");
            int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(inputData.Length, 16);

            Array.Resize(ref inputData, encryptionLength);

            byte[] cipherText;
            using (var aes = new AesManaged
            {
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
            })
            {
                using (var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(md5Bytes, iv))
                using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(inputData);
                    }

                    cipherText = cipherStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return GetBytesToString(cipherText);
        }

        // Align data
        public static int getAlignedSize(int currSize, int alignment)
        {
            int padding = (alignment - currSize % alignment) % alignment;
            return currSize + padding;
        }

        // Convert string to HEX
        public static byte[] GetStringToBytes(string value)
        {
            SoapHexBinary shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
            return shb.Value;
        }

        // Convert HEX to string
        public static string GetBytesToString(byte[] value)
        {
            SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary(value);
            return shb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Qt/C++ version

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCryptographicHash>
#include <QDebug>

#include "aes/aes.hpp"

namespace Encryption {

   const uint8_t iv[] = { 0xf0, 0xe1, 0xd2, 0xc3, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0x96, 0x87, 0x78, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x4b, 0x3c, 0x2d, 0x5e, 0xaf };

   inline int getAlignedSize(int currSize, int alignment) {
      int padding = (alignment - currSize % alignment) % alignment;
      return currSize + padding;
   }

   inline static QString encodeText(const QString &rawText, const QString &key) {
      QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Md5);
      hash.addData(key.toUtf8());
      QByteArray keyData = hash.result();

      const ushort *rawData = rawText.utf16();
      void *rawDataVoid = (void*)rawData;
      const char *rawDataChar = static_cast<const char*>(rawDataVoid);
      QByteArray inputData;
      inputData.append(rawDataChar, rawText.size() * sizeof(QChar) + 1);

      const int length = inputData.size();
      int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(length, 16);
      Q_ASSERT(encryptionLength % 16 == 0 && encryptionLength >= length);

      inputData.resize(encryptionLength);
      for (int i = length; i < encryptionLength; i++) { inputData[i] = 0; }

      struct AES_ctx ctx;
      AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, (const uint8_t*)keyData.data(), iv);
      AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(&ctx, (uint8_t*)inputData.data(), encryptionLength);

      QString hex = QString::fromLatin1(inputData.toHex());
      return hex;
   }

   inline static QString decodeText(const QString &hexEncodedText, const QString &key) {
      QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Md5);
      hash.addData(key.toUtf8());
      QByteArray keyData = hash.result();

      const int length = hexEncodedText.size();
      int encryptionLength = getAlignedSize(length, 16);

      QByteArray encodedText = QByteArray::fromHex(hexEncodedText.toLatin1());
      const int encodedOriginalSize = encodedText.size();
      Q_ASSERT(encodedText.length() <= encryptionLength);
      encodedText.resize(encryptionLength);
      for (int i = encodedOriginalSize; i < encryptionLength; i++) { encodedText[i] = 0; }

      struct AES_ctx ctx;
      AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, (const uint8_t*)keyData.data(), iv);
      AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(&ctx, (uint8_t*)encodedText.data(), encryptionLength);

      encodedText.append("\0\0");
      void *data = encodedText.data();
      const ushort *decodedData = static_cast<ushort *>(data);
      QString result = QString::fromUtf16(decodedData, -1);
      return result;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   QFile inputFile("data.txt");
   if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
   {
      QTextStream in(&inputFile);
      while (!in.atEnd())
      {
         QString random_s = in.readLine();
         QString test_enc = in.readLine();

         QString qt_enc = Encryption::encodeText(random_s, "pA5w0rd").toUpper();
         if(qt_enc != test_enc)
         {
            qDebug() << "Invalid decryption";
         }

      }
      inputFile.close();
   }

   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The C++/Qt version does not need `QCoreApplication a` and the call to `a.exec()`.  Those are only needed to run the Qt Event Loop, but there is nothing in the code that does.  More importantly, the application will appear to hang when `a.exec()` is executed as there is no way to leave it.

Comment: This example was more for encryption/decryption part than how to use Qt Application ;) - So on C#we create data.txt file that is random char encryption, and reverted way to read same file on Qt/C++ - so we like to read 'what was encrypted' (random text), decrypt using tiny aes, and validate.